# How to do custom transition in VSE?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I need to apply custom transition from a video to another video as below youtube video.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J30lNs0fRz0

can anyone explain me how to achieve that wipe transition using masks?

in this video it is not explained how to create those masks or transition in default mode and export it (ie. in, out) to video editing mode.

Comment: You would have to make these in the _3D View_ or _Compositor_ and then import that clip to the VSE.

Comment: Hey, thanks for reply. can you suggest any tutorial on this?

Comment: [This one uses a mask in the vse](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qK-k2N2Vxig) while [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TeqFTZgi_z8) uses blender to render the sequence to use as a mask.

Comment: Thank you for the links, I have watched both videos today and they were full of knowledge, this is what I was looking for. tomorrow I am going to create a testing project to master this techniques, thank you, you are the best.